# Изменить дату компьютера Delphi

Tags: winapi, delphi, время

Как изменить год,месяц,день с помощью делфи 7?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй это:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  SystemTime: TSystemTime; 
  NewTime, NewDate: string; 
begin 
  NewTime := '12:00:00'; 
  NewDate := '01.01.2006';  
  DateTimeToSystemTime(StrToDate(NewDate) + StrToTime(NewTime), SystemTime); 
  SetLocalTime(SystemTime); 
  // Tell windows, that the Time changed! 
  PostMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_TIMECHANGE, 0, 0); // * 
end;
```